# Wordpress Changing input values

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to write a plugin, I keep my address records in my cart and I want to automatically fill my data with the input values on the payment page, but I couldn't find it.

Following is my code:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'custom_override_checkout_fields');
function custom_override_checkout_fields($fields)
{
global $wpdb;

$list= $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * From wp_adress");
    foreach ($list as $value) {
        $firstname = $value->firstname;
        $lastname = $value->lastname;
        $phone = $value->phone;
    }
    $fields['billing']['billing_first_name']['value'] = '<?php echo $value->firstname ?>';
    $fields['shipping']['shipping_first_name']['value'] = '<?php echo $value->firstname ?>';
    $fields['shipping']['shipping_last_name']['value'] = '<?php echo $value->lastname ?>';
    $fields['billing']['billing_phone']['value'] = '<?php echo $value->phone ?> ';
    return $fields;
}
```

I just want to auto-fill the data in the database on the form checkout page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Will this Query not show all customer details since you are printing all the details in wp_adress.

Comment: yes it will show

Comment: The question is a bit strange for me.